# report link becomes ready - lubuntu installation

Tags: boot, usb, lubuntu

i wanted to install Lubuntu on a USB-Stick, from a IGEL Thin Client.
I have a bootable USB-Stick created on my Notebook. But when I start the Thin Client and wanted to Boot (Doesn't matter as live or as installation) I get the report "link becomes ready". My Network Card is running without problems, when I've installed an other OS.

Comment: You haven't provided Lubuntu release details (thus we don't know installer (`calamares` for modern Lubuntu, `ubiquity` for legacy...), but did you use the validate your ISO?, and further the write to your install media? (ie. "Check disc for defects" option) - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/Installing_lubuntu.html Chapter 1.1 Retrieving the image - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.1/retrieving_the_image.html
Chapter 1.2 Booting the Image - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.2/booting_the_image.html
Chapter 1.3 Installation - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.3/installation.html

Comment: the prior links assume the latest *stable* 19.10.  Lubuntu however is no different to any other Ubuntu, so usual links are Validate your ISO:  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and Validate your install media: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck (where CD refers to any media used including thumb-drive, ssd, hdd, network-share, dvd, & cd)